# Reportviewer not displaying in ASPX page - VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, reportviewer

I have a ReportViewer control in my .aspx page (rvSuggestions) which I am using to display a report (rptCountByUnit). The report uses the datasource objdsCountByUnit which is getting data using a stored procedure (tableadapter in dsCountByUnit.xsd). The stored procedure accepts the parameters @fromDate (passed from txtFrom on the page) and @toDate (passed from txtTo on the page).

When I open up dsCountByUnit.xsd and preview the data I get the results I expect, however when I run my page, rvSuggestions does not display. The DIV container expands down as though as it is there, however I just see a blank space.

Postback is triggered by btnSubmit and I have added the below code as explained on [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brianhartman/archive/2010/11/16/the-invisible-reportviewer.aspx) however it does not solve the problem (Strangely it did solve the problem on a different project I've been working on)

```
rvSuggestions.Visible = True
    rvSuggestions.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote
    rvSuggestions.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local
    rvSuggestions.LocalReport.Refresh()
```

This is my ReportViewer and Object data source:

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rvSuggestions" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" Width="870px" AsyncRendering="False">
            <LocalReport ReportPath="Reports\rptCountByUnit.rdlc">
                <DataSources>
                    <rsweb:ReportDataSource DataSourceId="objdsCountByUnit" Name="rptDataSet" />
                </DataSources>
            </LocalReport>
        </rsweb:ReportViewer>

        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="objdsCountByUnit" runat="server" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="GetData" TypeName="dsCountByUnitTableAdapters.getCountOfSuggestionsByUnitTableAdapter">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtFrom" Name="fromDate" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtTo" Name="toDate" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

This is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getCountOfSuggestionsByUnit 
@fromDate nvarchar(50), 
@toDate nvarchar(50) 
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT unit, COUNT (ref) as Suggestions
FROM suggestion.dbo.suggestions
where dateRaised BETWEEN @fromDate and @toDate
group by unit
```

Any ideas what may be causing this?

Comment: This may sound strange, but do a View Source in your browser when you see the blank div and see if the HTML is there to display the report. Trust me. :-)

Comment: Hi nunzabar, no the HTML is not there. Something is causing the reportviewer not to render?

Comment: So what is causing your DIV container to expand down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. I had added the parameters @fromDate and @toDate within the parameters folder of report data in the .RDLC file itself. I deleted these and the report is now displaying correctly.